# Why do ash (trees) and ash (burnt residue) have the same name?

Tags: etymology, old-english, homonyms, plants

**I've often wondered why [ash (trees)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fraxinus) and [ash (burnt residue)](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/ash) have the same name.**

---

I've looked up the origin of both words, but I don't see anything that explains why the names are the same.

From the *[Online Etymology Dictionary](https://www.etymonline.com/word/ash#etymonline_v_17923)*:

> ### ash (n.1)
>
> "powdery remains of fire," Old English *æsce* "ash," from
>   Proto-Germanic * *askon* (source also of Old Norse and Swedish *aska*, Old
>   High German *asca*, German asche, Middle Dutch *asche*, Gothic *azgo*
>   "ashes"), from PIE root **[*as-](https://www.etymonline.com/word/*as-?ref=etymonline_crossreference)** "to burn, glow." Spanish and Portuguese
>   *ascua* "red-hot coal" are Germanic loan-words.
>
> An ancient symbol of grief or repentance; hence *Ash Wednesday* (c.
>   1300), from custom introduced by Pope Gregory the Great of sprinkling
>   ashes on the heads of penitents on the first day of Lent. *Ashes*
>   meaning "mortal remains of a person" is late 13c., in reference to the
>   ancient custom of cremation. Meaning "Finely pulverized lava thrown
>   from a volcano" is from 1660s.
>
> ### ash (n.2)
>
> popular name of a common type of forest tree of Eurasia, North
>   America, and North Africa, Old English *æsc* "ash tree," from
>   Proto-Germanic * *askaz*, * *askiz* (source also of Old Norse *askr*, Old
>   Saxon *ask*, Middle Dutch *esce*, German Esche), from PIE root * *os-* "ash
>   tree" (source also of Armenian *haci* "ash tree," Albanian *ah* "beech,"
>   Greek *oxya* "beech," Latin *ornus* "wild mountain ash," Russian *jasen*,
>   Lithuanian *uosis* "ash").
>
> The close-grained wood of the ash is tough and elastic, and it was the
>   preferred wood for spear-shafts, so Old English *æsc* sometimes meant
>   "spear," as in *æsc-here* "company armed with spears," *æsc-plega* "war,"
>   literally "spear-play." *Æsc* also was the name of the Old English runic
>   letter that begins the word.

---

I understand that words can be **homonyms**, which are words that have the same spelling but **different meanings and origins**.

However, the fact that both words are related to **wood** makes me think that it might **not** be a mere coincidence.

Is there a reason why ash (trees) and ash (burnt residue) have the same name?

Comment: I feel like you've answered your own question. It is probably just coincidence if the Online Etymology Dictionary has them coming from different PIE roots, and they are different words (though similar) in most other Germanic languages.

Comment: @Wilson You might be be better off editing your question to use proper text for your quote rather than a screenshot image. It'll help people find your question... and possibly even answer it.

Comment: @TimFoster : Feel like whipping up an answer?

Comment: I always thought it was because the color of ash wood is very pale/white reminiscent of the color of ashes.

Comment: I would like to add a notę, not related to ethymology, by to interesting feature of ash tree wood. This winter i used this kind of timber as a fuel to heat my house and I observed that it leaves a lot of ash i the ash tray after buRning. A lot more than other species. Then I realised it is the same word in English and that is how I get there. Greetings!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**(1) The burden of proof**

Research methodology requires that, unless you can provide evidence for a relation between two variables, you must assume that no such relation exists. Put differently, if you cannot demonstrate that your hypothesis of relatedness of two words is true, you must operate under the assumption of the null-hypothesis that the two words are not related. Or to use a legal metaphor, if you cannot prove beyond any reasonable doubt that the accused is guilty, you must let them go free.

> There is no evidence that *ash* 'tree' and *ash* 'remains of fire' share a common historical root. We must therefore suppose that **the two words are not related** and that **their homophony is a mere coincidence**.

It is of course possible there is a relation between two variables and that there just isn't any empirical evidence to substantiate this. In other words, the hypothesis may be true even if you are not in a position to legitimately reject the null hypothesis. Or to use the legal metaphor again, the principle of "innocent until proven guilty" may sometimes result in guilty criminals who will not be convicted.

> It is possible that, thousands of years ago, speakers of Proto-Indo-European or Proto-Germanic did indeed connect the roots that would eventually give rise to *ash* 'tree' and *ash* 'remains of fire'. But if so, this potential link is lost in the mists of time and we are now **not justified to make this claim even if it might be true**.

**(2) Origins of the two words**

The etymologies provided in the question are generally adequate.
However, in order to show the two forms of *ash* do indeed appear to be etymologically unrelated, I will offer my own summary:

(a) ***ash* 'burned ashes'**

Several prominent cognates of the word *ash* exist in North- and West-Gemanic: Old English *æsce*, Old High German *aska*, Old Norse *aska*. From this we can easily reconstruct North-West-Germanic *['as.ka].
However, the Gothic cognate is surprising - it is *azgō*.
This phenomenon looks very much like a Germanic consonant alternations explained by [Verner’s Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verner%27s_law) (e.g. Ringe 2006: 275). Thus, the simplex n-stem, Primitive-Germanic *['as.kōn], may be a reanalysis of an originally complex word, perhaps derived or compounded, i.e. Proto-Germanic *['as] + *['gō-] forming *[as.'gō-].
What is the origin of *['as]? It's uncertain. One very good candidate is Proto-Indo-European * *h<sub>2</sub>es-* > * *as-* 'to burn, glow, dry up' (cf. Hittite *ḫāššā-* 'fireplace, hearth').
What is the origin of ['gō-]? This is extremely uncertain. There just isn't enough surviving material to determine what happened. All we know is that it's some extension with a velar. (e.g. Kronoon (2013: 38) suggests the source  * *dʰegʷʰ-* 'burn'.) (Interestingly, the Armenian cognate also has a velar extension *ačiwn* 'ashes' so that further investigations of this word might shed light on the origin of the second element of the compound.)

**Summary**: *ash* 'remains of fire' probably comes from some kind of complex word, quite possibly the Proto-Indo-European stem for 'burn' + a velar extension of unknown nature.

Proto-Indo-European: ??? (extremely uncertain)
Proto-Germanic: ??? *[as.'go-] (uncertain, perhaps compound)
North-West-Germanic:  *['as.ka] (certain, reanalysis as a simplex word)
Old English: *æsce*
Middle English *asshe*
Modern English: *ash*

(b) ***ash* 'tree'**

It is uncontroversial that this word derives from Proto-Indo-European * *h<sub>3</sub>osk-* > * *osk-* - the name for a common type of forest tree of Eurasia. The Proto-Indo-European * *o* regularly changes into * *a* in Germanic (e.g. Meier-Brügger 2002: 86), as in Latin *quod* English *what* etc., yielding * *ask-*. In West-Germanic, the word moved into the *i*-stem class, meaning that it took on the ending *-iz*. The earliest speakers of English, say c. 400 A.D., would have pronounced the word as *[ask.iz].

**Summary**: *ash* 'tree' goes back all the way to a Proto-Indo-European root with essentially the same meaning.

Proto-Indo-European: * *h<sub>3</sub>osk-* (certain, a simplex word)
West-Germanic: *['ask.iz] (certain)
Old English: *æsc(e)* (certain)
Middle English *assh(e)*
Modern English: *ash*

**(3) The words may not be that similar**

Because of the different etymological origins, the two senses of *ash* are actually pronounced differently in many Germanic languages.
Compare the different pronunciations in the following modern languages:

| language | ash 'burned residue' | ash 'tree' |
| --- | --- | --- |
| German | Asche | Esche |
| Dutch | as | es |
| Swedish | aska | ask |
| Faroese | øska | ask |
| Gothic | azgo | * asks (unattested) |

Even in Middle English, the most common spelling for *ash* 'burned residue' would retain a final *-e* while most spelling for *ash* 'tree' would occur without such an ending (but there are many exceptions).

> *Thei shuln be **ashe** vndir the soole of ȝoure feet.* (c1384 WBible(1), Dc 369(2))
> *A swyþe gret **Asch**.* (c1300 SLeg.Kenelm, LdMisc 108)

**References:**

Ringe, Donald (2006) *From Proto-Indo European to Proto-Germanic*. Oxford: Oxford University Press.
Kroonen, Guus (2013), *Etymological Dictionary of Proto-Germanic*. Leiden: Brill.
Meier-Brügger, Michael (2002) *Indogermanische Sprachwissenschaft*. Berlin: De Gruyter.

Comment: Holy smokes. That is a solid answer.

Comment: If "It is uncontroversial that this word derives from Proto-Indo-European \* h3osk" why don't you go into a little detail? Wiktionary has only Armenian (հացի (hacʿi)) down for \*Hh₃os-k-yeh₂, also Albanian (*ah* "beech") and, again, Germanic (\*askaz) under \*Hh₃es-k-; *-che* is a common suffix for plants, especcialy trees, in German (*Eiche, Lärche, Esche, Buche, Birke*); WT reconstructs the stem (pun intended) just as \*h3e(H)s; contrast \*(H)eh2s- or \*as- for short).

Comment: ... Also, unless WT misses important cognates, which is common, the ash tree (or birch or what) would seem to be rooted in western Europe so that the reconstruction for proto nuclear PIE or earlier is doubtful.

Comment: "There is no evidence that ash 'tree' and ash 'remains of fire' share a common historical root." – I don't see this paragraph in the question anywhere; where are you quoting it from?

Answer (score 6):

I think the fact the these two words are the same in English is probably just a coincidence. Although it can be tempting to come up with interesting links between the concepts of ash and the ash tree, I'd go with Occam's Razor - that the simplest explanation, requiring the least assumptions is the best explanation.

Thus as both forms have derivations going back to two different PIE roots, I think the likelihood is they only have the same form in English by chance. In most other Germanic languages, the words are similar, but not identical (e.g. - "askr" and "aska" in Old Norse, "Asche" and "Esche" in German). In fact, you could say it was almost inevitable that in one of the Germanic languages the two words would end up being the same.

However, it is interesting that the two derive from similar sounding PIE roots - *as and *askaz, which possibly date back, respectively, to *hehs and *hasy. So it's possible that there may have been some sort of link in very early PIE, or perhaps the progenitor of PIE, but I don't think we'll ever know for sure.

Hope that helps!

Comment: G *Asche* forms an Ablaut pattern with *äschern* "ashy", *(ein)äschern* "to inhume, cremate", which is basically homophone with *eschern* "made of ash tree wood".

Comment: And you misunderstand Occam's razor. You make *no assumptions*, which is less than the *the least*, and you offer *no explanation at all*. That's the equivilant of calling other people (the askee, in fact) idiots just because that required the least, or no assumptions.